JavaScript image lazy loading library that works based on src attribute
There are lots of libraries that use data- kind of attributes to specify the images. I'm looking for one that:

doesn't need any extra parameter except of class or even better a chosen selector provided to the library
works with both src parameter of <img> and background-image CSS of other elements
loads images based on screen scroll, either right when you scroll onto them or a bit earlier, I assume using a DOM observer
as a bonus, it could support videos too, but not a necessity

Examples of elements it should cover:
<img src="some/file.webp" class="some-lazy-loading-class" alt="" />
<div style="background-image: url('some/file.webp');" class="some-lazy-loading-class" />
<div style="background: url('some/file.webp') repeat-x fixed;" class="some-lazy-loading-class" />

